# how to find which memcached server store which key-value pair

Tags: java, hash, memcached, spymemcached

I am using two memcached server currently and storing the key value pair as above.after this I am not able to find out which server store which key-value pair...

I know that memcached distributed randomly .

If I remove one server and then I try to fetch all value as above

I will get half of the value null.

Is there any way I can find the which key-value pair is on which server.

please help

Answer (score 1):

The keys aren't distributed randomly they are hashed to a particular server and all of this is done by the client. In order to figure out which server they are going to you will need to figure out what the hash function is that your client is using. That will ultimately tell you which server a key is going to. Note that this process is totally up to the client and that memcached has no knowledge of other memcached servers.

Comment: Pls Explain with the help of code... or just give me ur email I will send the code i hv written and u tell me what are the things i need to change.And my email id is rajnaveen29@gmail.com Thanx in advance.